# How can one protect a Collada model in a SceneKit based app?

Tags: scenekit

If the model is read from a URL referencing a location somewhere in the cloud, it is loaded directly in to memory with this code?

```
[SCNScene sceneWithURL:url options:nil error:&error];
```

Is it still it vulnerable to pilfering by someone reading it from memory on a jailbroken device?  Is there any foolproof way to protect the model and files in scnassets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collada files are converted to some binary and proprietary format at build time when you build your app. This won't protect your assets but at least it won't be directly available as an open file format.
If you need to protect your assets you need to do your own encryption.
You can indeed also load remote assets but you need to convert those with "scntool" first (check how xcode converts the assets in the build logs) because Collada files can't be loaded directly on the device.